# Char Method javascript

Tags: javascript, char

Having issues...  Can anyone tell me what I did wrong on this JavaScript code:

```
function getname() {
    var the_name = window.prompt("Enter your first name", "");
    var first_char = the_name.charAt(0);

    if(first_char = "S") then {
        document.write(the_name);
    } else {
        window.alert("Please enter a name that starts with an uppercase S to have it displayed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: its not if() then{}, its if (){}. no need of then

Comment: And use ===, not just =

Comment: You are not writing VBS here... Why is there a `then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**then** is not valid syntax, and use **==** on string compare

```
function getname() 
{
var the_name=window.prompt("Enter your first name","");
var first_char = the_name.charAt(0);

if(first_char== "S") 
{
    document.write(the_name);
}
else
{
    window.alert("Please enter a name that starts with an uppercase S to have it displayed.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(first_char= "S")
```

to

```
if(first_char== "S")
```

[JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `==` to compare your value instead of `=`:

```
if(first_char == "S")
```

as well as remove `then` in your if-else condition (Actually I thought that is your explanation though :P )

Answer (score 0):

There is no **then** in `if-else` syntax. Also comparison operator is `==` not `=`

```
function getname() 
{
var the_name=window.prompt("Enter your first name","");
var first_char = the_name.charAt(0);

if(first_char== "S") 
{
    document.write(the_name);
}
else
{
    window.alert("Please enter a name that starts with an uppercase S to have it displayed.");
}
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I took the "then"  out.  I got my Programming languages mixed up.   But it's still not working.